# Create limit date for login in PHP Script

Tags: php, login-script

This simple script doesn't need database, the usernames and passwords will define in the script.
How can I build the script to define a date for each username and password so that after the date expires the ability to log in using those credentials to also expire?

**Like this:**

```
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(  
'you' => 'yourpassword' => '12-03-2012'  
'username2' => 'yourpassword2' => '12-05-2012'  
);
```

Script Demo: http://demos.savasplace.com/password/

```
<?php
##################################################################
##           Sava's Place.com Password Protect                  ##
##       Visit http://savasplace.com for more scripts           ##
##################################################################
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'sava' => 'sava',
  'you' => 'yourpassword'
);

// Require username or not
// If you want to use username and password login leave this true.
// If you want only to request a password set it for false.

define('USE_USERNAME', true);

// To password protect your pages you need to include this file in them
// To get the correct code for inclusion open password.php?code in your broswer

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
  die('<center><font face="Verdana" size="2">Include following code into every page you would like to protect, at the very beginning (first line):<br><br><strong>&lt;?php include("' . __FILE__ . '"); ?&gt;</strong></center></font>');
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  setcookie("verify", ''); // clear password;
  die('<center><font face="Verdana" size="2">Logged out.</font></center>');
}
if(!function_exists('showLoginPasswordProtect')) {
function showLoginPasswordProtect($error_msg) {
?>
<!-- And this is the output -->

<html>
<head>
<title>Login to access this page</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<style>
* {
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:12px;
}
a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
}

input {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.bodyform {
border-color: #000000;
border-style:solid;
border-width: 3px;
width:400px;
}
.title {
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #000000;
padding: 5px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><br /><br />
<div class="bodyform" align="center">
<form method="post">
<div class="title">
<strong>Access restricted - Login Below:</strong>
</div>
<div style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;">
<font color="red"><strong><?php echo $error_msg; ?><strong></font><br /><br />
<?php if (USE_USERNAME) echo '<table>
<tr>
<td align="left">Login:</td>
<td align="right"><input type="input" name="access_login" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>'; ?>
<td><input type="password" name="access_password" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
<br />
Powered by <a href="http://savasplace.com" target="_blank">Sava's Place Password Protect Script</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  die();
}
}
if (isset($_POST['access_password'])) {
  $login = isset($_POST['access_login']) ? $_POST['access_login'] : '';
  $pass = $_POST['access_password'];
  if (!USE_USERNAME && !in_array($pass, $LOGIN_INFORMATION)
  || (USE_USERNAME && ( !array_key_exists($login, $LOGIN_INFORMATION) || $LOGIN_INFORMATION[$login] != $pass ) ) 
  ) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("Incorrect password.");
  }
  else {
    setcookie("verify", md5($pass));
    unset($_POST['access_login']);
    unset($_POST['access_password']);
    unset($_POST['Submit']);
  }

}
else {
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['verify'])) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
  }
  $found = false;
  foreach($LOGIN_INFORMATION as $kay=>$val) {
    if ($_COOKIE['verify'] == md5($val)) {
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!$found) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `<font>` tags? Seriously? They are deprecated for **years**!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` to convert your date to time numeric value and compare it to you current data also converted to a numeric value and in case it is greater than the one you specified then return false on login.

```
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(  
    'you' => array('pass' => 'yourpassword', 'date' => '12-03-2012'), 
    'username2' => array('pass' => 'yourpassword2', 'date' => '12-05-2012')  
);


if(strtotime($LOGIN_INFORMATION['you']['date']) > time())
{
    exit();
    // show error message or anything
}
else
{
    // login or whatever you would like to happen here in case the date did not expired
    // check password, etc
}
```

[php function strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[php function time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Comment: how can i include **strtotime if command** into the this script?  
Which part must be put this command?

Comment: @Amirreza you just write the code sample I gave you above into your .php file at the beginning or where ever you are doing the actual login, if this is something you know. Probably the best is to put it after `$pass = $_POST['access_password'];
`, but what do I know?. Maybe you try to manage doing at least this, if anything else puzzles you.

Comment: How can i correct edit this code for put in the main script? **if(strtotime($LOGIN_INFORMATION['you']['date']) > time())**

Answer (score 0):

You could change `setcookie` to:

`setcookie("verify", md5($pass), time()+3600);`

and then the cookie would expire after 1 hour and the user would no longer be logged in. If you wanted the cookie/login to last longer then you would change the expire parameter to a longer time.